# Why do all three boxes move when I try to move only one?

Tags: html, css, web, margin

Hopefully somebody can help me with my issue.
I'm trying to make my own website, but when I try to move one of the three individual boxes(see picture), all three of them move.  [three boxes issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD6mr.jpg)

[The same issue also happens with the social icons box but I'm less concerned with that section]

I'm hoping someone can take a look at the code and hopefully tell me where I've gone wrong.

[My Website Files](https://www.mediafire.com/?dzaqua94re5zai3)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please paste the code in your question. Noone will download your code and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put `position:block` in your css. There is no `position:block` in css. You have to use display property to that. I have change your box div's css to  `display: inline-block;` and made few changes in width too.(using calc).

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-image: url(../css/images/background/backgroundimage.jpg);
}

/* HEADERBAR */
div#headerbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(237,87,82, 0.65);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
}

.leftlogo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'roboto+condensed', sans-serif;
}
.leftlogo span {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(237, 87, 82, 0.8);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.version {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* CODE TEST */
.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 21px/40px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
.button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #126b72;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}

div#updatesbox {
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 2px #000000;
}

.updatesbox1 {
    width: 443px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
}

.updatesbox2 {
    width: 443px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 2px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0px #000000,2px 2px 20px 6px #000000;
}

.twitter {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.tweet {
    color: white;
}
.facebook a {
    color: rgba(273, 87, 84, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.facebookicon {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.steam a {
    color: rgba(273, 87, 84, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.steamicon {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.instagram a {
    color: rgba(273, 87, 84, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.instaicon {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.tweet a {
    color: rgba(237, 87, 84, 1); 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
/* ALTERNATING TEXT */
#tickertape{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 14.5px;
    text-align: center;
    width:400px;
    height:20px;
}
.tickertape {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: #000;
}

#subtickertape{
    position:absolute;
    width:443px;
    height:20px;
}

.subtickertapefont{
    font:bold 12px Verdana;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgba(237, 87, 84, 0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}

.subtickertapefont a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* BODY CONTAINER BOX */

div#bodycontainer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgba(237, 87, 84, 0.3);
    width: 90%;
    height: 800px;
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}

#bodycontainer #insidebox {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(32.3% - 7.5px);
    height: 500px;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: rgba(237, 87, 84, 0.2);
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}

#bodycontainer #centerbox {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(32.3% - 7.5px);
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}

#rightbox {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(32.3% - 7.5px);
    height: 710px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: rgba(237, 87, 84, 0.2);
    border: 2px dashed #000;
    margin-left: 15px !important;
}
```

change your stylesheet.css to this and then you can move each box individually. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're awesome! I've taken note of the changes and will learn from this!

Comment: Happy To help you.